# Add inline onfocus and onblur to an input/div programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, function, events, addeventlistener

I have a div that doubles as an input textarea users can type in (using Quill JS).

```
<div class="myeditor" placeholder="Type text here">Text Area</div>
```

I need the div to have an onfocus and onblur to detect when the user has click in (or is outside of) the input textarea. But the way this is added is programmatically so I **can't** hardcode into the html itself something like:

```
<div class="myeditor" placeholder="Type text here" onblur="myFunction(false)" onfocus="myFunction(true)">Text Area</div>
```

Instead I need to add the onblur/onfocus after creation.

Please note - I really prefer it to be inline like the above, not as an invisible listener. Is their something like .innerHTML but affecting the **actual** html of the div? Thoughts?

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve here? Please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you need.

Maybe you can use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to set the listeners explicitly so it will be visible when you inspect the html:

```js
document.querySelector('.myeditor').setAttribute('onclick', 'onEditorClicked()');

function onEditorClicked() {
  alert('clicked');
}
```

```html
<div class="myeditor" placeholder="Type text here">Text Area</div>
```